# Associating and iterating in C++

Tags: c++

I've got a situation where I want to use an associative container, and I chose to use a std::unordered_map, because it's perfectly feasible that this container could be used to hold millions or more of elements. But now I also need to iterate in order. I considered having the value types link to each other in a list, but now I'm going to have issues with memory management.

Should I change container, say to a std::map? Or just iterate once through my unordered_map, insert into a vector, and sort, then iterate? It's pretty unlikely that I will need to iterate in an ordered fashion repeatedly.

Comment: "It's pretty unlikely that I will need to iterate in an ordered fashion repeatedly." - Out of interest, when you picked `unordered_map`, did you think it was pretty unlikely that you'd need to iterate in order at all? I'd say `map` is the simplest available option, and hence the baseline against which you should be measuring optimizations (such as `unordered_map` plus a separate sort or ordering).

Comment: @Steve: I knew that I would have to, but forgot, as it's not necessary for the first stage.

Comment: certainly if I'd gone to the trouble to write a `hash` function for my key, I'd be keen to stick with `unordered_map` too :-)

Comment: @Steve: I didn't really do that. Just forwarded some hashes to the Standard hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you know the O() of the various operations of the two alternatives you've picked.  You should pick based on that and do a cost/benefit analysis based on where you need the performance to happen and which container does best for THAT.

Of course, I couldn't possibly know enough to do that analysis for you.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Boost.MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/index.html), specifying the unordered (hashed) index as well as an ordered one, on the same underlying object collection.

Possible issues with this - there is no natural mapping from an existing associative container model, and it might be overkill if you don't need the second index all the time.